# how to bind a TCP socket without listening in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I want to reserve a port for the duration of the application, but the application shouldn't be listening on the port all the time. Hence I want to decouple the `bind()` call from the `listen()` call.

The UDP/Datagram socket in nodejs has a `bind` function. But I couldn't find an equivalent for it in the "normal" (TCP) socket API.

Is it possible to bind without listening?

Comment: Why? Listening on it immediately won't do any harm, except that clients can connect sooner.

Comment: Just listen but don't do anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create unwrapped TCP sockets:

```
const net    = require('net');
const TCP    = process.binding('tcp_wrap').TCP;
const socket = new TCP();

// Bind is done here.
socket.bind('0.0.0.0', 3333);

console.log('bound');

// Then, at some later stage, if you want to listen,
// you can use the previously created (and bound) socket.
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('listening');
  const server = net.createServer((conn) => {
    console.log('got connection');
    conn.end('bye\n');
  }).listen(socket);
}, 5000);
```

**EDIT**: to instantiate a socket on Node v9.3.0 and higher, you need to pass an extra argument to the constructor:

```
const TCPWrap = process.binding('tcp_wrap');
const { TCP } = TCPWrap;
const socket  = new TCP(TCPWrap.constants.SERVER); // or .SOCKET
```

The difference is the ability to distinguish between the two types of socket when using [`async_hooks`](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html).

Comment: 'Raw TCP socket' is a contradiction in terms, and this does exactly what the OP claims, rightly or wrongly, he doesn't want to do.

Comment: _"Is it possible to bind without listening?"_. Yes, and I'm showing how (and also how to listen on it at a later stage, as he wants to decouple binding and listening). And with "raw TCP socket" I don't mean a "raw socket", I mean an unwrapped (by Node) socket.

Comment: You'll have to explain that. Mere code is not an answer. How can code that calls 'listen()` possibly not be listening?

Comment: @EJP again, the code is showing how to separate binding from listening. The call to `listen()` _does_ listen, but at that point the port is already bound (by the `socket.bind()` call that was executed earlier).

Comment: So it should say so in your answer. Not down here.

Comment: This no longer works in node v.9.3.0. The `tcp_wrap` module will now intentionally commit suicide if you try to access it from javascript: https://github.com/substack/tcp-bind/issues/2

Any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: @MichaelMatthewToomim see my edit, and also my answer on GH.

Comment: Your answer continues to both bind and listen.

Comment: @EJP that's correct, as per the question. Another reason why you'd want to decouple `bind()` and `listen()` is if you want to bind to a privileged port but run the connection handler without root privs, so you'd bind as root and `process.setuid()` down to a regular user's UID. However, that was not what was asked, so I didn't put that in the (accepted) answer.